# Valid PGN variations?

Tags: pgn

I've received the following PGN text that I suspect invalid:

```
8.f4 
    {0.22/17 0 last book move}
8...e5 
    ( 8...b5 
       ( 8...Qb6 
           ( 8...Qc7 9.a3
```

What exactly the position the moves come from is unimportant. Please note the PGN text has **four** 8th Black moves (`8...e5`, `8...b5`, `8...Qb6`, `8..Qc7`), and two of them (`8...Qb6` and `8..Qc7`) are **under** `8..b5`.

I suspect this is a mistake because the alternative Black moves should be represented like the diagram:

[image]

I generated the diagram with the Scid vs PC software. Please note the alternative Black moves are written in parallel. For example, `8...Qb6` and `8..Qc7` **are not** included inside the `8...b5` bracket.

Some softwares (e.g. Scid) are able to read it, but some fail (e.g. ChessX). My own PGN implementation can't handle the nested structure.

**Q**: Is the PGN text I posted valid? What does the PGN specification say?

**EDITED:**

The game is [here](http://smallchess.com/Others/MaybeInvalid.pgn). Open the game in a text editor, and you will see the following:

```
e5 
    { 0.22/17 237 } 
    ( 8...b5 
        ( 8...Qb6 
            ( 8...Qc7 9.a3
```

Comment: Not an answer here, but I couldn't get the PGN to compile with my reader.

Comment: I'll edit and post the whole game.

Comment: @Bad_Bishop I edited and posted a link.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't parse for me. But if I changed to (8...b5) (8...Qb6) etc. then it is fine.

Comment: @Bad_Bishop What software you have?

Comment: PgnViewer from Lokasoft (https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/p/pgnviewer/9wzdncrdlzrh)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good question. This nested notation (also called: recursive annotation variation, RAV for short) is uncommon but valid[*]. In the example you provide, most online PGN readers have no problem parsing and accounting for all the variations and subvariations. So the way to read it is as follows: the nested structure is composed of independent variations, only if there's a closing parenthesis then it is an actual subvariation (so a specific branch out of a previous variation). An example from your PGN: `8... Qc7` is a variation, `(9.Qe1...)` is a subvariation and `(10.Bf3...)` is a subsubvariation. So the nesting is: `(8... Qc7 (subvariation (subsubvar...) ))`.

Various libraries/modules may not have a built-in parsing system to tackle such PGN structure[**], so you may have to extend this on your own. For further reading, Tim Harding also explains the nested notation and its lack of implementation rather more succinctly [here](http://portablegamenotation.com/LittlePGN.html), I briefly quote:

> An RAV (Recursive Annotation Variation) is a sequence of movetext
>   containing one or more moves enclosed in parentheses. An RAV is used
>   to represent an alternative variation. The alternate move sequence
>   given by an RAV is one that may be legally played by first unplaying
>   the move that appears immediately prior to the RAV. Because the RAV is
>   a recursive construct, it may be nested. ...
>
> Some software may find it
>   hard to handle nested variations too. Palview3 was the first
>   freely-available PGN software, that I am aware of, that could create
>   with variations in HTML pages, and it is restricted to two levels of
>   notes (three levels counting the actual moves of the game). For most
>   purposes, this is sufficient. Most Java Viewers can only show the
>   actually played moves, except as text notes, but playing through a
>   Palview3 web page is close to the experience of playing it through in
>   a program like ChessBase: a major advance for chess webmasters.

That said, nowadays, there are various online pgn-readers that already do this, some examples (so if you paste your PGN onto either of these, it can be fully read and displayed).

- https://www.chess.com/analysis-board-editor
- https://chesstempo.com/pgn-viewer.html
- http://www.apronus.com/chess/wbeditor.php

You may find additional information on the standards of PGN [here](http://www.saremba.de/chessgml/standards/pgn/pgn-complete.htm). I will get back to you if I find other potentially useful elements.

---

[*]: just to make sure, I also quickly parsed the text to make sure all parentheses are properly closed.

[**]: for example, the `chess.pgn.read_game` method from `python-chess` fails to fully read this PGN, it only sees the main variation upto move `8... e5.`